# Ant script reply to prompt

Tags: jenkins, ant, antbuilder

I'm new to ant scripts and what I needed in my .xml is a reply to a prompt.

Basically when deploying a prompt that takes Y/N input needs an answer for deployment to continue.

So in my ant script how would i get it to reply with Y?

This script in also run at the  level so I can't place anything after this line and putting command = "command1; command2" isn't working either

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the program that's taking the input? Something launched by the Ant script with the `<exec>` task, or a completely separate process?

Comment: Please show the part of the build file that is relevant here.